# Lock a file in bash using flock and lockfile

Tags: bash

i spent the better part of the day looking for a solution to this problem and i think i am nearing the brink ... What i need to do in bash is: write 1 script that will periodicly read your inputs and write them into a file and second script that will periodicly print out the complete file BUT only when something new gets written in, meaning it will never write 2 same outputs 1 after another. 2 scripts need to comunicate by the means of a lock, meaning script 1 will lock a file so that script 2 cant print anything out of it, then script 1 will write something new into that file and unlock it ( and then script 2 can print updated file ).
The only hints we got was the usage of flock and lockfile - didnt get any hints on how to use them, exept that problem MUST be solved by flock or lockfile.

edit: When i said i was looking for a solution i ment i tried every single combination of flock with those flags and i just couldnt get it to work.

I will write pseudo code of what i want to do. A thing to note here is that this pseudocode is basicly the same as it is done in C .. its so simple, i dont know why everything has to be so complicated in bash.

script 1:

place a lock on file text.txt ( no one else can read it or write to it)
read input
place that input into file ( not deleting previous text )
remove lock on file text.txt
repeat

script 2:

print out complete text.txt ( but only if it is not locked, if it is locked obviously you cant)
repeat

And since script 2 is repeating all the time, it should print the complete text.txt ONLY when something new was writen to it.

I have about 100 other commands like flock that i have to learn in a very short time and i spent 1 day only for 1 of those commands. It would be kind of you to at least give me a hint. As for man page ...

I tried to do something like flock -x text.txt -c read > text.txt, tried every other combination also, but nothing works. It takes only 1 command, wont accept arguments. I dont even know why there is an option for command. I just want it to place a lock on file, write into it and then unlock it. In c it only takes flock("text.txt", ..).

Comment: This question is... rather unclear. If you could write a **short** piece of sample code that attempts to accomplish your goal, and describe how its actual behavior differs from your desired behavior, that would be a better starting place.

Comment: (`man flock` shows some fairly clear-to-understand examples in terms of where to start with its use).

Comment: The main idea of the homework is to make you learn something from it rather than to just produce a solution. If you spent better part of the day looking for a solution without trying anything than you just wasted the time.

Comment: ...and, err, **no**, the equivalent C call is **not** `flock("test.txt", ...)` -- the use of a file descriptor is an important detail. You'll notice that the best-practices use from bash _also_ uses a pre-opened file descriptor, just as the C version does.

Comment: Next time you're asking a question, by the way, you'd do well to get your temptation to rant under control. There are certainly places where bash is needlessly complicated (many of them mandatory for compliance with the POSIX sh standard), but the specific things you're complaining about here aren't things where bash is complicated -- they're just things where you don't know it yet. Rich Hickey's talk "Simple vs Easy" is a good place to start re: teasing apart the difference between "complicated" and "hard" in your head.

Answer (score 17):

Let's look at what this does:

```
flock -x text.txt -c read > text.txt
```

**First**, it opens `test.txt` for write (and truncates all contents) -- before doing anything else, including calling `flock`!

**Second**, it tells `flock` to get an exclusive lock on the file and run the command `read`.

However, `read` is a shell builtin, not an external command -- so it can't be called by a non-shell process at all, mooting any effect that it might otherwise have had.

---

Now, let's try using `flock` the way the man page suggests using it:

```
{
  flock -x 3                       # grab a lock on file descriptor #3
  printf "Input to add to file: "  # Prompt user
  read -r new_input                # Read input from user
  printf '%s\n' "$new_input" >&3   # Write new content to the FD
} 3>>text.txt                      # do all this with FD 3 open to text.txt
```

...and, on the read end:

```
{
  flock -s 3  # wait for a read lock
  cat <&3     # read contents of the file from FD 3
} 3<text.txt  # all of this with text.txt open to FD 3
```

You'll notice some differences from what you were trying before:

- The file descriptor used to grab the lock **is in append mode** (when writing to the end), or in read mode (when reading), so you aren't overwriting the file before you even grab the lock.
- We're running the `read` command (which, again, is a shell builtin, and so can *only* be run directly by the shell) by the shell directly, rather than telling the `flock` command to invoke it via the `execve` syscall (which is, again, impossible).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I saw similar code online but there were parts i didnt understand. For instance, how does the first flock know that 3 means text.txt ? Because of that 3>>text.txt in the end ?

Comment: Exactly. The `3>>text.txt` opens `text.txt` on file descriptor 3 for the entire block it's applied to. I tried to explain that in the code comments. As soon as the block exits, the file descriptor is closed, so the lock is implicitly released. (This works the same way in C -- closing the file descriptor a lock is attached to implicitly releases that lock).

Comment: Thank you. What bothered me was that descriptor in code is applied after we used it but now i understand. Btw did you mean to use ( ) or { } for the block ?

Comment: ( ) is not a code block but a subshell -- as such, its use has a great many side effects (including performance overhead). I meant what I wrote. (To be clear, a subshell would also work here in this specific case -- but it wouldn't work if, say, you were reading content from the locked file into a variable you wanted to access from the parent process).