# Acquire lock for /etc/passwd file in Bourne shell script

Tags: sh

I have an embedded system where user management in `/etc/passwd` file is done usually automatically with a Bourne shell script. However, it might happen that sometimes `/etc/passwd` file is edited with a text editor by `root` user or by `passwd` utility. Is there a way to program Bourne shell script in a way that it locks the `/etc/passwd` file during its execution so that other programs are not able to edit the file at the time? Also, this script should detect if `/etc/passwd` file is not opened by other processes. I could use following solution from [Wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045):

```
# locking example -- CORRECT
 # Bourne
 lockdir=/tmp/myscript.lock
 if mkdir "$lockdir"
 then    # directory did not exist, but was created successfully
     echo >&2 "successfully acquired lock: $lockdir"
     # continue script
 else
     echo >&2 "cannot acquire lock, giving up on $lockdir"
     exit 0
 fi
```

However, this ensures only that two instances of this script are not running simultaneously. I also have a BusyBox `lock` available which behaves similarly to `flock`, but again, as far as I can tell, I can't protect other processes editing `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28227739/lock-a-file-in-bash-using-flock-and-lockfile

Answer (score 0):

The `vipw` command may provide this for you and you can customize the editor using the `EDITOR` environment name.

See `man vipw` for details.

Comment: Unfortunately `vipw` is not an option. This is an embedded system and I'm hardly able to install anything there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to program Bourne shell script in a way that it locks the /etc/passwd file during its execution so that other programs are not able to edit the file at the time?

That is called *mandatory file locking* and the answer is probably no.  In Linux that requires the `mand` option when the file system is mounted.  I would guess that's a nonstarter in your environment, but if it's an option (so to speak) have a look at your favorite resource for how to proceed from there.

It's not shell-script functionality you need.  For one process to prevent another from opening a file requires kernel support.  Unix programs traditionally use advisory locks, or cooperate some other way.  **vipw**(8) is an example of how that's done.